# Vue on:click Seems to Call All Methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently in the process of learning Vue, and I ran into an issue that I'm hoping someone can help me with.

While using the v-on:click directive to call a method, all other instance methods are being called if the method is also used elsewhere.

HTML:

```
<div id="exercise">
    <div><button class="test" v-on:click="newCheck()">New Challenge</button>
        <p >Success check is: {{ passCheck }}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="roll" v-on:click="roll20()">Roll!</button>
        <p>You Rolled a {{ roll20() }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#exercise',
    data: {
        yourRoll: '10',
        passCheck: '10',    
    },
    methods: {
        roll20: function(){
            this.yourRoll = Math.round(Math.random()*19)+1;
            return this.yourRoll;
        },
        newCheck: function(){
            this.passCheck = Math.round(Math.random()*19)+1;
        }
    }
});
```

When {{ roll20() }} is used in the second paragraph, clicking the 'New Challenge' button runs both roll20() and newCheck(). However, if {{ yourRoll }} is used in the second paragraph instead, this doesn't happen.

In both instances, clicking 'Roll!' only runs roll20().

Can someone help explain what is happening here?

Here is a codepen of the issue:
[Codepen of code](https://codepen.io/digitalhodgepodge/pen/KRdQvj)

Note: I ended up bypassing the issue by using a different approach, but I would still like to know why this was happening: [Working Approach](https://codepen.io/digitalhodgepodge/pen/KRdRxx?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Whenever* the DOM is updated, it will run `roll20` again, because of the line:

```html
<p>You Rolled a {{ roll20() }}</p>
```

So anything that triggers an update will trigger `roll20` by consequence.

Now, because of the template:

```html
<div><button class="test" v-on:click="newCheck()">New Challenge</button>
```

We know that when you hit the `New Challenge`, it calls the `newCheck` method.

And because the `newCheck` method changes a variable (`passCheck`) that is used in the template:

```js
    newCheck: function(){
        this.passCheck = Math.round(Math.random()*19)+1;
    }
```

That is used here:

```html
    <p>Success check is: {{ passCheck }}</p>
```

Changing `passCheck` will trigger a DOM update. And DOM updates will call `roll20` automatically (because of the reason stated in the first paragraph of this answer).

---

## Working around it:

The simplest way is just not to call `roll20` in the template. And, as `roll20` actually updates a `yourRoll` property:

```
    roll20: function(){
        this.yourRoll = Math.round(Math.random()*19)+1;
        return this.yourRoll;
    },
```

You could just use `yourRoll` in the template, instead of `roll20()`:

```
<p>You Rolled a {{ yourRoll }}</p>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/acdcjunior/pen/PePBeo

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I wasn't aware how the virtual DOM functioned here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="exercise">
        <div><button class="test" v-on:click="newCheck()">New Challenge</button>
    <p >Success check is: {{ passCheck }}</p>
    <!-- 3) Call a function to output a random float between 0 and 1 (Math.random()) -->
        </div>
        <div>
        <button class="roll" v-on:click="roll20()">Roll!</button>
    <p>You Rolled a {{ yourRoll }}</p> <!-- this changed -->
        </div>
</div>

new Vue({
    el: '#exercise',
    data: {
        yourRoll: '10',
        passCheck: '10',    
    },
    methods: {
        roll20: function(){
            this.yourRoll = Math.round(Math.random()*19)+1;
        },
        newCheck: function(){
            this.passCheck = Math.round(Math.random()*19)+1;
        }
    }
});
```

Try this it workes fine!Just output your data property because in one your was calling the method! [See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/ekuLmqfm/)